# How can i timeout/terminate a running Flow from within the CordApp in Corda

Tags: kotlin, corda

I implemented two Flows(Initiating and Responder Flow) that run every X minutes from my Service. They make use of both the send and receive method. When one Node goes down the Flow stays in memory and does not return or throw an Exception. This turns into a problem since after some time the node will crash because too many Flows are running at the same time.

My question is how can i timeout a Flow automatically after X TIME. Or how can i terminate a Flow from the CordApp at all?

Things that i have tried are:

1. kill flow from RPCOps - no use, since i want to delete it from the Cordapp
2. kill flow from shell - no use, since i want to delete it in the Code under certain conditions
3. Make Flow inherit from TimedFlow and set the parameters accordingly - The docs say that this never actually kills the Flow but just restarts it

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem you are facing is that there are too many flows running at the same time. If you are using Corda Open Source v4.x, keep in mind that it is single threaded, so if you need to have a several flows running in parallel you should switch to Corda Enterprise, which is multi-threaded.

More specifically about the killing of flows. In your case it seems that the Responder flow has some issues, so causing the Initiating flow to wait forever for a response that never arrives. It is normal behavior. Since the flow is started from the Initiating flow, you need to kill that, you cannot kill the Responder flow from the Initiating one (which is what you are asking in this question).

What you want to do is also theoretically wrong. It would imply that, in a distributed network with Initiating and Responder flows running on two different nodes belonging to two different Organizations, the first one could control the operations of the other. This is not how DLTs/blockchains are supposed to work, it is instead normal in a standard client/server architecture.

The only way to kill the Initiating flow is from either the node terminal or from an external client using CordaRPC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My Flows work fine actually, i was just speaking hypothetically when one Node goes offline the Flows would still be around waiting for the Node to come online again and new Flows would be launching every X Minutes... I found a way to timeout my initiating Flows by extending TimedFlow. At every start/restart the Flow checks how many minutes have passed since it was launched the very first time and if it exceeds X minutes i throw a FlowException